# Remap input keys in /dev/input level

Tags: keyboard, input

I want to remap input keys from keyboard and mouse, but I need it to be in low level, so that reading `/dev/input*` shows remapped functions.

Example:
I have regular keyboard and I want `ENTER` key to emit `left mouse` button click.

Is that possible and how?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [keyfuzz](http://0pointer.de/lennart/projects/keyfuzz/)? It can map keys by their scancodes. Not sure you can map a key to a mouse click using that tool though.